# The meaning of <class>::<class>():interface(),interface()

Tags: c++

I've seen the above in some c++ code and wonder what is happening.  Can anyone explain what this means to me?

```
SomeManager::SomeManager()
   : m_someinterface(NULL)
   , m_someinterface(NULL)
{
}
```

Comment: what part don't you understand?

Comment: I understand its a constructor for class.  The bit I dont get is how the interface side works.  I'm new to c++

Comment: Search for and read about *constructor initializer lists*.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean the following

```
SomeManager::SomeManager() : m_someinterface(NULL) , m_someinterface(NULL)
{
}
```

It is a definition of a constructor of class `SomeManager` that have mem-initializer list

```
m_someinterface(NULL) , m_someinterface(NULL)
```

where its subobjects (data members and/or base class subobjects) are initialized.

Take into account that data members shall have different names like for example
m_someinterface1 m_someinterface2.

Here is a simple example

```
class A
{
public:
    A();

private:    
    int x;
    int y;
};

A::A() : x( 10 ), y( 20 ) {}
```

After creating an object of the class like

```
A a;
```

its data members `a.x` and `a.y` will have correspondingly values 10 and 20.

Or another example where the base class constructor is called explicitly

```
class A
{
public:
    A( int x, int y ) : x( x ), y( y ) {}

private:    
    int x;
    int y;
};

class B : piblic A
{
public:
    B( int );

private:    
    int z;
};

B::B( int z ) :  A( z / 10, z % 10 ), z( z ) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant but couldn't get the formatting to work.

Comment: @Gavzooka See my updated post.

Comment: `m_someinterface` might be really an interface and a base class of `SomeManager`, it is not necessarily a member

Comment: @tobi303 I updated my post